# BEGIN block and variable declaration

Tags: perl, syntax

Is it valid perl to set a variable in a `BEGIN` block, but declare the variable outside the `BEGIN` block?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.10.0;

my $var;

BEGIN{ $var = 10 }

say $var;
```

Comment: why don't you try it out? If it's invalid, perl will tell you

Comment: I tried it but I don't like it - maybe I hoped someone would say "......, but don't use it".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it's valid.  In fact, you must do it that way, or `$var` would be local to the BEGIN block and not available in the rest of your program.  To quote [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Private-Variables-via-my%28%29):

> A `my` has both a compile-time and a run-time effect. At compile time, the compiler takes notice of it. ... Actual initialization is delayed until run time, though, so it gets executed at the appropriate time, such as each time through a loop, for example.

The compile-time effect is why you can access the variable in the BEGIN block.  Be aware that any initialization on the `my` will take place *after* the BEGIN block is evaluated (and thus will overwrite any value the BEGIN might set.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, but you might want to be careful with this pattern, because something very similar will work differently than you might expect:

```
my $var = 5;
BEGIN { $var = 10 }

say $var; # 5
```

Comment: For everybody who wonders: this is because the `BEGIN` block runs before `$var = 5` and thus, `$var = 5` changes the value from 10 to 5 even though they appear in opposite order in the code.